# SpringBoot: No lee parametro por POST

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

estoy intentando hacer una petición con el método post a una api hecha en Spring. El problema es que me lanza el siguiente error y no consigo solucionarlo.

```
Object {
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Required Long parameter 'idONG' is not present",
  "path": "/v1/ONG/mostrar",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": "2020-04-02T10:30:55.506+0000",
}
```

este es el código de la peticion:

```
const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ idONG:1})
        };
        fetch('http://192.168.0.17:8090/v1/ONG/mostrar', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ong:data, loading:false}));
```

y este el código del controlador de la petición, que me gustaría no tener que modificar:

```
@PostMapping("/mostrar")
    public MONG mostrarONG( @RequestBody @RequestParam("idONG") Long idONG) {
        return ONGService.mostrarONG(idONG);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como en el tipo de dato es un `long`, solo tienes que enviar el valor como tal sin convertirlo a JSON.

Cambia:

```
body: JSON.stringify({ idONG:1})
```

Por:

```
body: 1
```

Y en el metodo tienes que quitar el atributo `@RequestParam` porque este se utiliza cuando deseas mapear parametros desde la url.

```
@PostMapping("/mostrar")
public MONG mostrarONG(@RequestBody Long idONG) {
    return ONGService.mostrarONG(idONG);
}
```

---

La diferencia entre `@RequestBody` y `@RequestParameter` es que `@RequestBody` mapeara los parametros desde el cuerpo de la solicitud mientras que `@RequestParameter` los mapeara de query string de la url. Por ejemplo la siguiente url funcionara con `@RequestParameter` pero no con `@RequestBody`:

```
http://localhost:8080/mostrar?idONG=434
```

En este caso, tu parametro mapeara al valor 434.

En resumen: no puedes combinar `@RequestBody` y `@RequestParameter`

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda